# VB.NET and SQL Server Express application deployment

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, deployment, multi-user

I have developed an application using VB.NET and used SQL SERVER Express as the database back end.
The application has 5 user profiles.(Each user profile provides different services).

Deployment reqiurements :
The application is to be deployed on a LAN with 10-20 machines.
Any user profile can be accessed from any machine.
Any changes to the database entries should be reflected on all machines.

I am confused about how I should achieve this deployment. According to my research :

1.The database should be deployed on one machine . This machine will acts as the database      server .

My problem(s) : 
I am familiar with accessing databases on local machine but how to access a remote database?.
Is the connection string the only thing that needs to be addressed or are there any other issues  too?
Do I need to install SQL SERVER on all machines or only on the server machine ?
Do I have to deal with concurrency issues (multiple users accessing/modifying same data simultaneously) or is it handled by the database engine?

2.The application can be deployed in 2 ways :
   i. Storing the executable on a shared network drive on the server.Providing shortcut on desktop of each machine.
  ii. Storing the executable itself on each machine.

My Problem(s) :
    How does approach 1 work ? (One instance of an executable running on multiple machines ? :s)
    In approach 2 , will the changes in database entries be reflected on all machines appropriately?
    In approach 2, if there are changes to the application , is there any method to update it on all machines ? ( Other than redeploying it on each machine )
    Which approach is preferable?
    Do I need to install the .NET framework all machines?

Will I have to make any other system changes ( firewall,security,permissions) ?
If given a choice to install the operating system on each machine ,which version of windows is preferable for such an application environment ?

This is my first time deploying a multi-user database application on a network.I'll be very grateful for any suggestions/advice,references,etc.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'Deploy'? Are you sending a CD to a client, or are you on site with access to all the machines inc the server?

Comment: @peterG I am on site with complete access to all machines.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: You will need to create SQL Server 'roles' for each of your 'profiles'.  A given user will be assigned one or more or those 'roles'.  Each of your tables, views, stored procedures, and triggers will need to be assigned one or more roles.  This is a messy business, this is why DBAs get paid lots of money to lounge around most of the time (I'm kidding, don't vote me down).

Question 2: If you 'remote in' to a server, you'll get the server screens, which are quite a bit duller than the workstation presentation.  Read up on 'One Click', this gives you the ability to detect an updated application on a host, and automatically deploy the update to the user's machine.  This gets rid of the rather messy business of running around to 20 machine installing upgrades every time you fix something.

Comment: Thank you.'One Click' does provide a convenient solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you have hands-on access to all the machines your task is comparatively simpler.
Install SQL Express on your chosen db server. You should disable the 'hide advanced options' in the installer; this will allow you to enable TCP/IP and the SQL Browser service; also you may want mixed-mode authentication - depends on your app and whether the network is domain or peer-to-peer. The connection string will need to be modified as you are aware; also the default configuration of Windows firewall on the server will block access to the db engine - you will need to open exceptions in the firewall for the browser service and SQL server itself. Open these as exceptions for the exes, not as port numbers etc. Alternatively, if you have a firewall between your server and the outside world, you may decide to just turn off the firewall on the server, at least on a temporary basis while you get it working.
No, you don't need to install any SQL Server components on the workstations.
Concurrency issues should be handled by your application. I don't want to be rude but if you are not aware of this maybe you are not yet ready for deploying your app to production. Exactly what needs to be done about concurrency depends on both the requirements of your application and the data access technology you are using. If your application will be used mostly to enter new records and then just read them later, you may get away without too much concurrency-handling code; it's the scenario where users are simultaneously editing existing records where the problems arise - but you need to have at least basic handling in place. 
Re where to locate the client exe - either of your suggestions can work. Simplest is local installation on each machine using an .msi file; you can place a master copy of the msi on the server. You can do stuff with login scripts, group policies, etc, or indeed clickonce. To keep it simple at this stage I would just install from an .msi onto each machine - sounds like you have enough complexity do get your head around already. 
One copy of the exe on the server can be handled in a more sophisticated manner by Terminal Server Citrix, etc.
Either way assuming your app works correctly, yes all changes will be made against the same db and visisble to all workstations.
Yes you will need .net framework on all machines - however, it may very well already be there. Different versions of Windows came with different versions of the Fx built-in and or updated via Windows Update; also of course it depends which ver you built your exe against.
Right I hope there is something helpful in that lot. Good luck.